# DFS of a graph using vector

Tags: c++, graph, c++14

I want to implement the adjacency list rep of graph using vectors, and I was using a program meant for implementing adjacency list using linked list as a guide, and I'm unable to do so. Here's my tried code upto now:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class graph{
    int v;
    vector<int> *adj;
    void DFSutil(int v, vector<bool> &visited){
        visited[v]=true;
        cout<<v<<" ";
        for(int i=0;i<v;i++){
            if(!visited[i])
                DFSutil(i,visited);
        }
    }
public:
    graph(int v){
        this->v = v;
        vector<int> adj[v];
    }
    void addEdge(int v,int w){
        adj[v].push_back(w);
    }
    void DFS(int source){
        vector<bool> visited;
        DFSutil(source, visited);
    }
};
int main()
{
    graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0,1);
    g.addEdge(0,2);
    g.addEdge(1,2);
    g.addEdge(2,0);
    g.addEdge(2,3);
    g.addEdge(3,3);
    g.DFS(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are several conceptual errors in the code you posted. I recommend you start with learning C++ before jumping into graphs.

Comment: @TanveerBadar Kindly edit the code then, and please don't demotivate, I understand you can't help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There were a few errors in initialization:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
class graph{
    int v;
    vector<int> *adj;
    void DFSutil(int v, bool visited[]){
        visited[v]=true;
        cout<<v<<" ";
        vector<int>::iterator i;
        for(i=adj[v].begin();i!=adj[v].end();++i){
            if(!visited[*i])
                DFSutil(*i,visited);
        }
    }
public:
    graph(int v){
        this->v = v;
        adj = new vector<int>[v];
    }
    void addEdge(int v,int w){
        adj[v].push_back(w);
    }
    void DFS(int source){
        bool *visited = new bool[source];
        for(int i=0;i<source;i++)
            visited[i]=false;
        DFSutil(source, visited);
    }
};
int main()
{
    graph g(4);
    g.addEdge(0,1);
    g.addEdge(0,2);
    g.addEdge(1,2);
    g.addEdge(2,0);
    g.addEdge(2,3);
    g.addEdge(3,3);
    g.DFS(2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are still many conceptual errors in this. Read about Rule of 3 and Rule of 5. And RAII. And memory management. And why including `bits/stdc++.h` is not a good idea.